# Yahoo/Google Email Message Copy after sending message through a website contact form

Tags: email, gmail, yahoo-mail

This is a workflow automation question.

I have a Yahoo/Google email(non-employer email). I want to send a message using a contact form on a website. This could be any website. On the contact form, I indicate my Yahoo/Google email and write a message.

Issue: When I get a reply from the website, where I wrote my message, I don't have a way to retrieve the message I wrote previously.

Objective: I want to save the copy of the message in my Yahoo/Google email after I send the message using the website's contact form.

Please let me know how to do that.

Thank You